# The NSNotificationCenter is never executed

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

This is my code.

Here create the observer to Notification called `Example` into ViewController

```
- (void)addObserverExample
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(example:)
                                             name:@"Example"
                                           object:nil];
}


- (void)example:(NSNotification *)notification{
   NSLog(@"Example!!!");
}
```

From `viewDidLoad` register my observer

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [self addObserverExample];
}
```

In my second ViewController. When tapped a button excute this code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Example" object:self.dictKeys userInfo:nil];
```

The problem I have is that the notification is never executed.

Any idea.

Comment: Have you verified that the call to `postNotificationName` is actually made? Is the view controller that is observing still in memory when the 2nd view controller posts the notification?

Comment: Yes. When in my second viewController inspect `[NSNotificationCenter default]` the `Example` exist.

Comment: 1. NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Example")  2. Don't register a notification object with viewDidLoad.

Comment: @ElTomato #2 - why not?

Comment: Are you sure that your `viewDidLoad` is called? For example if you have a derived controller, and the code is in your base view controller, if you forget to call `[super viewDidLoad]` in your derived controller's `viewDidLoad`, it won't get called. Can you verify that your code is called by setting up a breakpoint?

Comment: Yes, I am sure about this... The `viewDidLoad` is called @CanPoyrazoğlu

Answer (score 0):

Have created demo for NSNotificationCenter as per your question and it's working fine for me. Here it is the link of that code: [NSNotificationCenter Demo](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SVVTgU8y9hzb9bQUH15Ut7nhpGd4IXzY)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self addObserverExample];
}

- (void)addObserverExample
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(example:)
                                                 name:@"Example"
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)example:(NSNotification *)notification{
    NSLog(@"Example!!!");
    NSLog(@"%@",notification.userInfo);
}

- (IBAction)btnFireNotification:(id)sender {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Example" object:nil userInfo:@{@"key" : @"value"}];
}
```

Comment: Do let me know if this works for you. And if this answer helped you then please help me to get privilege into this community. Thanks In Advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you're having may be related to the fact that in your second view controller, you're passing `self.dictKeys` in the `object` parameter. 
If you want to pass data via the `NSNotificationCenter`, you should use the `userInfo` parameter instead.

Darshan's example does this the correct way.